# How to tackle daylightsaving time of UK in a server running in CET like netherlands

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, dst

Our server is running in netherlands but users uses the application in UK .

For UK 2017-03-26 02:30:00 is valid date-time but not in Netherlands.

I am using the code to convert the time by setting the timezone . But its not giving me right output.

```
    String toDate ="2017-03-26 02:30:00";//Valid Time in UK
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    // Use London's time zone to format the date in
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("London"));

    System.out.println("Date and time in London: " + df.parse(toDate));
```

Output from Program : Date and time in London: Sun Mar 26 04:30:00 CEST 2017

**Output Required : Date and time in London: Sun Mar 26 02:30:00 CEST 2017**

Java version used : 1.7 . Can not use joda time for some dependency.

Comment: Is the timezone "London" correct? I think it should be "Europe/London"

Comment: I tried doing `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"))` at the beginning, but the output is almost correct: `Sun Mar 26 02:30:00 BST 2017` (**BST** instead of **CEST**)

Comment: Thanks Hugo. It worked for me .. I got what I wanted .

Comment: But why setting the timezone in simpledateformat does not work ??

Comment: London doesn't use CEST.  [BST is correct](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/uk/london).  (BST = "British Summer Time").  Also, I don't see you doing any conversions here, except you're implicitly converting the output `Date` object from `df.Parse` to a string when you concatenate, which will use the default time zone - not the one assigned to `df`.  What is the output from `java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getID()`?

Comment: Also, the `date` variable created in the second line in your code above is not used...

Comment: Hi Matt , This is not the actual code .. I wrote this some sample code that looks like the actual code .. By mistake I created the date object . In actual code I do date formatting .. I ran the getID() .. The output is Europe/Berlin

Comment: Are the inputs and outputs you gave us from the code you gave us? Or from your actual code?  You can certainly give us a reproduction, but don't  assume the outputs are the same without running it.  If indeed your default time zone is `Europe/Berlin`, then the code shown here should give an output of 3:30 CEST. [See conversion here](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20170326T013000&p1=136&p2=37).

Comment: Indeed.... http://ideone.com/H6cpm2

Comment: Yes the input and the output is from the sample code . As told by Ole its is giving 4:30 CEST because its making the zone UTC.

Answer (score 1):

First a detail, `TimeZone.getTimeZone()` is dangerous, if it doesn’t recognize the ID string, it will tacitly give you GMT. Exactly in London this is so close to the correct you may get fooled for a while. `TimeZone.getTimeZone("London")` gives you UTC (or GMT). As Stefan Freitag pointed out, it has to be `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London")` for the correct British time zone.

Next a very common misunderstanding: A `Date` object does not have a time zone in it. It’s a point in time only. So how come it is printed as `Sun Mar 26 04:30:00 CEST 2017`, where `CEST` obviously refers to a time zone (Central European Summer Time, used in the Netherlands)? When printing the date, you are implicitly invoking `Date.toString()`. This methods unconditionally prints the time according the default time zone for the JVM. Therefore, setting the time zone for the `DateFormat` you used for parsing has no effect here. And therefore changing the JVM’s time zone setting, as Hugo did in a comment, works. The other way of getting correct output for British users is to format the Date back into a string using a `DateFormat` with British time zone.

If you use Hugo’s trick in the beginning, before creating the `DateFormat`, it too will have the British time zone, and you need not call `df.setTimeZone()` (but you may if you think it makes the code clearer, of course).

Look forward to using Java 8 or later some day. The new date and time classes in [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) generally don’t come with the surprises experienced with the old ones.

Comment: And for the record… Much of the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: @BasilBourque I would have stressed this point more if the original poster had not said “Can not use joda time for some dependency.” I assumed the ThreeTen Backport would also be a nogo in this case. Hope I’m wrong. :-)

Comment: I understand, that's why I posted as a comment.  I am speaking to posterity, not you. ;-)